# Bind jQuery event only after the DOM loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my static version of a page, I have a js call:

```
$(document).on('click','#id_tag', function() {
```

The element with the id #id_tag won't be in the DOM when the document is first loaded.  How do I have this event bind only when the DOM element appears?

Note: In an earlier version, I miswrote the id as `.id_tag`  Hence comments below

Comment: How does the element get added to the dom, could you not add it at the smae time? Also, ids shouldn't have any `.` in them

Comment: This should work.. Only thing i can guess is the `#` instead of `.` in your code..

Comment: since you are using event delegation, even if the element is added later it should work

Comment: Graham, the element is added when a user clicks a button.  The DOM content is returned by the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click','.id_tag', function() {
     if($(this)!=null){
         //do ur stuff
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

OR this -

```
$(function(){
   // DOM Ready - do your stuff 
   $(document).on('click','.id_tag', function() {
     if($(this)!=null){
         //do ur stuff
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

DOM READY FUNCTION WILL DO THE JOB!

simpliest example will be like this!

```
$(function(){
  var $doc = $(document);
  $doc.on('click','#id_tag', function() {
    alert('id_tag is clicked!');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Concise:

```
$(function(){
    $(this).on('click', '.id_tag', function() {
        //handle click
    });
});
```

Explanation: This causes jQuery to attach a click listener to the entire `document` element. When it is clicked, jQuery then checked to see if it was an `id_tag` class element that was actually clicked.